# asp.net login adds redundant table

Tags: asp.net, forms, layout, authentication, overriding

I am trying to do following:

```
<asp:Login id="loginControl" OnAuthenticate="loginControl_Authenticate" runat="server">

    <LayoutTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox id="UserName" runat="server" placeholder="Benutzername"></asp:TextBox>

        <br/>

        <asp:TextBox id="Password" runat="server" textMode="Password" placeholder="Passwort"></asp:TextBox>

        <br/>

        <br/>

        <input type="checkbox" id="remember">&nbsp;<label for="remember">Eingeloggt bleiben.</label>

        <br/><br/>

        <asp:button id="Login" CommandName="Login" runat="server" Text="Einloggen"></asp:button>

    </LayoutTemplate>

</asp:Login>
```

The aforeshown code is embedded this way:

```
<form class="seamless filling" ID="loginControlForm" runat="server" >

    <msa:Login ID="loginControl" runat="server" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/eService/KundenStartseite.aspx" />

</form>
```

Very much to my annoyance, however, ASP.NET considers it necessary to put my overridden Template inside a *table*, making it look quite ugly. How can I tell ASP.NET to let me actually override its built-in layout?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<asp:Login id="loginControl" RenderOuterTable="False" OnAuthenticate="loginControl_Authenticate" runat="server">
```

see the `RenderOuterTable="False"`